# Issue while using the wso2 api manager product api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to explore the product api to create api using curl commands.
    I followed the documentation to create the access token . It worked fine till then
    But when i try to invoke a publisher service using the below command, I get an error

```
 curl -v  -k -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token obtained>" http://<host ip address>:9763/api/am/store/v0.14/apis 


* About to connect() to <host ip address> port 9763 (#0)
*   Trying <host ip address>...
* Connected to <host ip address> (<host ip address>) port 9763 (#0)
> GET /api/am/store/v0.14/apis HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: <host ip address>:9763
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <access token obtained>
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2019 15:03:08 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
<
* Connection #0 to host <host ip address> left intact
{"code":401,"message":"","description":"Unauthenticated request","moreInfo":"","error":[]} 

I have rechecked my login credentials while generating the client key and then the client and client key while generating the token. I am not sure what is going wrong. Can anyone help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have provided relevant scope when generating the token. Every resource has a particular scope as defined in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APICollection#apisGet. In this the scope is apim:api_view. In the token response, check whether you have obtained the relevant scope.